# Matching characters in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'd like to extract some digits that are not followed by star, here is the example :

```
1
0
0*1543
27 123*5464
11 1007*
998*7586
13
997*686
```

I've tried using this regex and some more but none of them worked:

```
(\d+)[^\*]
```

What I'm looking for is to get all digits unless they're followed by a star. Here is how the output should look like :

```
1
0
27
11
13
```

My plan was to write regex and use groups to extract these values. I'm using [this site](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test my regex.

Update :
I'm not looking for match the digits after the *, meaning I only want numbers at the start of the line. thanks

**Update II:**

Aftert further diging into matches given by regex(from Dr.Kameleon)

```
(?<!\*)(?<![0-9])([0-9]+(?!\*)(?![0-9]))
```

I get an extra match as it can be seen here :

http://regexr.com?30l69

I don't want to match `505` in `222*123 505` . All other matches are perfectly matched.

Looks like this regex need small tweaking but I wasn't able to tweak it i.e. `(?<!\*)(?<![0-9])(?<!\\s)([0-9]+(?!\*)(?![0-9]))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try this one :** (demo : http://regexr.com?30l47)

```
([0-9]+(?!\*)(?![0-9]))
```

**or this** (if you want JUST the first parts, as in your example) - http://regexr.com?30l4a **:**

```
(?<!\*)(?<![0-9])([0-9]+(?!\*)(?![0-9]))
```

Comment: that is almost it, just I don't want to match the digits after the *, meaning I only want numbers at the start of the line. thanks

Comment: @London Of course, I imagine, what you want could also be done by splitting your string by `"*"` and `" "` (space) and then getting the first element of the array... but I'm by no means a java guru, so I'll leave that to you... :-)

Comment: @London LOL (to be honest I hate Java...). You're welcome - glad to have helped! :-)